# Ignore some .scss files in vscode live sass compiler

Tags: css, sass, visual-studio-code

I  am using vscode live sass compiler to compile my `sass` code to css and am trying to destructure my code such that I have codes for specific function in separate file then I can import them to the main `.scss` all at once so that one css file to be generated as this is all I need because am using react.

I have been succesfull so far my problem is that even the other refactored code that I already imported are compiled to `css`. I don't need this.

How can i tell live sass compiler to ignore them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `liveSassCompile.settings.excludeList` setting to exclude specific folders. All Sass/Scss files inside the folders will be ignored.

You can use negative glob pattern too if you want to exclude a specific file or files inside this folders.

Examples:

Default value

```
"liveSassCompile.settings.excludeList": [ 
     "**/node_modules/**",
     ".vscode/**" 
]
```

Negative glob pattern -  if you want exclude all file except `file1.scss` & `file2.scss` from path/subpath directory, you can use the expression

```
"liveSassCompile.settings.excludeList": [
    "path/subpath/*[!(file1|file2)].scss"
]
```

You can find more info [here](https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-sass-compiler/blob/master/docs/settings.md).

Answer (score 4):

There are two way through which you can prevent file to be compiled to generate separate .css file

1. File(.scss) name starting with underscore( **_** ) well not be compiled to generate css file
2. If you have a folder with multiple .scss files you can exclude all files within folder and its subfolders through vscode setting.json file

Code

```
"liveSassCompile.settings.excludeList": [
    "**/node_modules/**",
    ".vscode/**",
    "**/YOUR_FOLDER/**"
 ],
```

replace ***YOUR_FOLDER*** with your desired folder

example I have 'vender' named folder with all bootstrap source code files

[Example:SCSS files in vender folder and it's subfolder will not be compiled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VD4q4.png)

Comment: The second solution didn't work for me. Not sure why. Did read the documentation and tried a few answers' code here on stackoverflow. Little luck. But the "_" prefix you mentioned is working and is ok for now.

Comment: Works for me. Note that there are no starting or trailing slashes at very beginning or end of the path names (e.g. "/**/YOUR_FOLDER/**"). 

Extension settings give me an error message for not having these, yet including them prevents the folder from being excluded.